# Amazing Follower Tweaks and Meeko: No option to leave service!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

So I've downloaded the "My home is your home" mod so that my chosen followers will stay at my house when I don't need them. Before this mod I did not check if Meeko could leave my service, so I'm unsure if this mod is messing him up.

My two other follers, Sofia (John Jarvis and Christine Slagman) and Garm (Wolfgrimdark), both leave my service and stay where I tell them to. (when I speak to Garm he joins my service automatically, but he'll leave when I ask.) I am also using Meeko reborn to change Meeko to a white husky, so the issue may be related to this mod.

I've tried removing Amazing Follower Tweaks and the option pops up, but he won't join my service anymore. I was trying to get the kids to keep Meeko and apparently they don't recognize that you have a dog with the aft mod enabled, but I've given up on that issue because I can't get rid of him now.

Has anyone else had a similar problem or a fix?
*my follower count is 0 and my animal count is 0

Edit: Ok so making a clean save with AFT does work and Meeko stays where I told him to! As long as I never ask him to join me ever again...

Answer (score 0):

For future reference

console:

> set playerfollowercount to 0

If you have a NPC waiting for you to meet up and do a quest just go and finish it, I don't know how this code will affect that situation.